# Newtonsoft Json: How to serialize special value to undefined in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, json.net

I want to serialize a key value map

```
var data = new Dictionary<string, object>();
data["prop"] = null;
```

such that the serialized output looks like:

```
{
   "prop": undefined
}
```

I've tried using JsonSerializerSettings like so:

```
var stringValue = string.Format({0}, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data,
                new JsonSerializerSettings
                {
                    NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Include,
                    ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
                }));
```

But this gives me

```
{
    "prop": null
}
```

Is there a way to somehow get the undefined as value for prop? 
It would be okay for me if I needed to use a specific string value to indicate the undefined value, like

```
data["prop"] = "undefined";
```

Comment: Undefined is not valid JSON, it is a JavaScript construct.

Comment: You're right. I was mixing up the serialized form with the JS object representation. I think I will need to go with null values then.

Comment: Do you still need an answer then?

Comment: No. I will vote for closing my question as duplicate, since there are other questions going into the same direction already.

Comment: @ScottyD0nt, not strictly true. It's true that it's not a valid value but a missing key is `undefined`. `{}` and `{ foo : null }` are different valid JSON objects. In the first `foo` is `undefined`. The concept as such doesn't explicitly exist but does so implicitly. The problem is `CSharp` doesn't have a native concept of `undefined`. You need something like an `Option<T>`  monad to do that.

Comment: @CervEd A missing key returning undefined is a behavior of JS Objects, nothing to do with JSON.